# JPEG2000 Encoder and Decoder

Tags: encoder, decoder, jpeg2000

I am working on the JPEG2000 compression as a part of my research work. I want some kind of open source libraries that can decode the JPEG2000 image and give me its DWT coefficients. And then I would like to encode these coefficients to get the image.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about [openjpeg](https://code.google.com/p/openjpeg/)?

Comment: openjpg will not give me the DWT coefficients. It only converts from one compression to another. Is there a way this can be done using openjpg?